# Partitioning one set such that the sum of of each partition equals a value of a second set

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, approximation

Given a set $V=\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ of values and a set $S=\{s_1, ..., s_m\}$ of sums, partition $V$ into $\tilde{V_1}, ..., \tilde{V_m}$, such that $\sum_{v \in \tilde{V_k}} v = s_k + \epsilon_k$ with $\sum_{k=1}^{m} \left | \epsilon_k \right | = min$. The $\epsilon_k$ represent the error for each sum and can be positive or negative.

In my application, it is known that $\sum_{v \in V}{v} = \sum_{s \in S}{s}$, if that simplifies the problem.

I have been looking through a lot of combinatorial optimization problems, but can't find one  that matches mine (or at least I am unable to infer which is equivalent).

I am looking for a name or any info for further reading or some insight into how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem via mixed integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,k}$ indicate whether value $v_i$ appears in partition $k$.  Let $\epsilon^+_k \ge 0$ and $\epsilon^-_k \ge 0$ be slack variables.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{k=1}^m (\epsilon^+_k + \epsilon^-_k)$ subject to linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^m x_{i,k} &= 1 &&\text{for $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$}\\ 
\sum_{i=1}^n v_i x_{i,k} - \epsilon^+_k + \epsilon^-_k &= s_k &&\text{for $k\in \{1,\dots,m\}$} 
\end{align}
To recover the partition from the resulting optimal solution $x^*$, take $$\tilde{V}_k=\{i\in\{1,\dots,n\}:x^*_{i,k}=1\}.$$

Comment: Yes, let me modify the answer.